# PHP omit an include from specific page

Tags: php, include

I have a PHP site that includes a header (menu nav and logo).
I have a section in my site that I would like to include a DIFFERENT header
I am struggling with this.  Any help would be appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
 <div id="wrapper">  
    <? include('inc/header.inc.php'); ?>
        <? require('process/build_page.php'); ?>
        <? require('inc/footer.inc.php'); ?>

    </div>
```

I want to include the following header on a specific section called "my-association"

```
<? include('inc/header_ma.inc.php'); ?>
```

The process/build_page code looks like this:

```
<?
global $full_uri;

class BuildPage
{

    function BuildPage()
    {
        global $full_uri;

        if($full_uri)
        {
            $this->build_path();
        }
        else
        {
            exit();
        }
    }

    function build_path()
    {
        global $full_uri;

        $uri_array = explode("/", $full_uri); # make uri into an array divided by /
        $clean_uri = array_filter($uri_array); # remove empty elements
        unset($clean_uri[1]); # remove base part of uri
        $clean_uri = array_values($clean_uri); #reset array key to start with 0

        # if array is empty the homepage is being requested
        if(empty($clean_uri)){
            $clean_uri[0] = 'home';
        }

        # build uri to point to include file
        $new_path = "content/";
        $new_path .= implode("/", $clean_uri);
        $new_path .= ".inc.php";

        $this->build($new_path);

    }

    function build($path)
    {
        $output = "";
        $output .= $this->get_include_contents($path);
        echo $output;
    }
    function get_include_contents($filename)
    {
        if (is_file($filename))
        {
            ob_start();
            include $filename;
            $contents = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            return $contents;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function print_array($data)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
        die();
    }

};

$buildpage = new BuildPage();

?>
```

Please advise!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I've missed something but wouldn't this do the trick?

```
<div id="wrapper">  
    <? 
    $change_header = array('/special_page_1','/special_page_2','/special_page_3');

    if(in_array($full_uri,$change_header))
        include('inc/header_ma.inc.php');
    else
        include('inc/header.inc.php');
    ?>
        <? require('process/build_page.php'); ?>
        <? require('inc/footer.inc.php'); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried something similar too.  But neither your nor my code worked.